# Google doc doesn't want to convert to a pdf after table data reaches 2000 lines

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I want to convert a dynamically created document to a PDF. It works when there is not a lot of data in the doc. However if my table's lenght goes above a certain value it does not want to work. Does anyone know what I can do?

```js
function myFunction() {
    var tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("FOLDER_ID");
    var tempDoc = DriveApp.getFileById("tEMP_DOC_ID");
    var tempFile = tempDoc.makeCopy(tempFolder);
    var table = tableDat2.map(function(r) {
        return [r[0].toString(), r[1], r[4], Number(r[7]).toFixed(2), Number(r[9]).toFixed(2), Number([10]).toFixed(2), Number(r[11]).toFixed(2)]
    });
    table.unshift(headingData[0]);
    var DocUse = DocumentApp.openById("DOCUMENT_O_USE ID");
    var body = DocUse.getBody();

    var style = {};
    style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 6;


    body.replaceText("{shopName}", shopName);
    body.replaceText("{Street}", street);
    body.replaceText("{Suburb}", suburb);
    body.replaceText("{City}", city);
    body.replaceText("{Country}", country);
    body.replaceText("{telephoneNumber}", telephoneNo);
    body.replaceText("{email}", email);
    body.replaceText("{orderDate}", orderDate);
    body.replaceText("{sdd}", sDD);
    body.replaceText("{rd}", rD);
    body.replaceText("{parameter}", param);
    body.replaceText("{order}", orderNo);
    body.replaceText("{totalValue}", totalVal);
    body.replaceText("{totalWeight}", totalWeight);
    body.replaceText("{totalPallets}", totalPal);
    body.appendTable([headingData[0]]);

    var tab = body.appendTable(table);

    tab.setAttributes(style);

    DocUse.saveAndClose();

    var pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("FOLDER'S ID");
    var PDF1 = DocUse.getAs(MimeType.PDF);

    var PDF = pdfFolder.createFile(PDF1).setName("Quotation of: " + shopName + "Order no: " + orderNo);
    return PDF;
}
```

Comment: It does not want to work is not very helpful.

Comment: Please provide the error log

Comment: The error log is as follow: Exception: Conversion of Google Drive document  to application/pdf failed.

Comment: How do you know that the error is thrown when the "lines reach 2000"? Can you share a  copy of your sheet, removing sensitive information please?